# Read From Multiple CSV Files in a loop in shell

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have a requirement of reading some *CSV* files one by one, *CSV* files will be named  *Test1.csv*,*Test2.csv*, etc.  The code:

```
     #!/bin/bash
     IFS=","
     FILES=/CSVFiles/*
     CSVNAME=Test
     n=1
     for f in $FILES 
    while read Column1 Column2 
    do
            echo $Column1
            echo $Column2
    done < "$CSVNAME"$n.csv
    n=$((n+1))
```

Returns these errors:

> ./ReadCSV.sh: line 23: syntax error near unexpected token `while'
>
> ./ReadCSV.sh: line 23: `while read Column1 Column2

Comment: Please specify about how many  _Test**n**.csv_ files there are, and whether the files need to be displayed in any particular order.

Comment: That is a good point to ask as it happens globbing will not consider file order into account

Comment: It seems unlikely that `/CSVFiles/` is *really* in the root directory.   Please `cd` to that directory and show the output of `readlink -e Test1.csv`.

Comment: @agc there may be n number of csv files.There are two columns in each csv and need to print value of each column row wise.

Comment: @nkm, I don't know what "*row wise*" means, please give an example of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a

```
do
```

after

```
for f in $FILES
```

But if I understood your intentions correctly, you could improve the example using the code below:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /CSVFiles/Test*.csv # Use file globbing to get the files
do
/*Use a stream editor like awk to print the lines*/
  awk -v FS="," '{
  /* if you want the columns in separate lines */
  print $1;
  print $2;
  }' "$file"
done
```

**Edit 2 :** If you need to take the file order into consideration, the code below helps

```
#!/bin/bash
#Count the total number of files using stat and grep
total=$(stat -f /CSVFiles/Test*.csv | grep -c '^[[:blank:]]*File:')
#User c-style for-loops in bash
for((i=0;i<="$total";i++))
do
awk -v FS="," '{
      /* if you want the columns in separate lines */
      print $1;
      print $2;
      }' "Test${i}.csv" # Feeding the file names in order
done
```

Comment: Test1.csv: No such file or directory error at for loop

Comment: @nkm : What is the exact path to the folder containing those csv files. Are you using my code exactly as it is?

Comment: corrected path and able to read first csv but second csv printing value of 1st csv itself.

Answer (score 1):

How about this.

```
IFS=","
FILES=/CSVFiles/*
cat $FILES|while read Column1 Column2
do
echo $Column1
echo $Column2
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of the OP script seems to be equivalent to this one-liner:

```
cut -d, -f1,2 /CSVFiles/Test*.csv | tr , '\n'
```